# Split Stringified JSON

Tags: node.js, json

I am writing an array of objects to a json file

`fs.writeFileSync('fixturesString.json', JSON.stringify(dateFixtures,null,4),'utf8');`

It writes to the file in the below format:

```
[
{
    "season": "2018-19",
    "competition": "Premier League",
    "matchDay": "2018-12-08",
    "homeTeam": "Bournemouth",
    "awayTeam": "Liverpool"
},
{
    "season": "2018-19",
    "competition": "Premier League",
    "matchDay": "2018-12-08",
    "homeTeam": "Arsenal",
    "awayTeam": "Huddersfield"
},
{
    "season": "2018-19",
    "competition": "Premier League",
    "matchDay": "2018-12-08",
    "homeTeam": "Burnley",
    "awayTeam": "Brighton"
}
```

]

Is there a method to use so that it writes to the file with each object on its own line eg.

```
{"season":"2018-19","competition":"Premier League","matchDay":"2018-12-08","homeTeam":"Bournemouth","awayTeam":"Liverpool"},
{"season":"2018-19","competition":"Premier League","matchDay":"2018-12-08","homeTeam":"Arsenal","awayTeam":"Huddersfield"}
```

Many Thanks for any help

Mos.

Comment: in which programming language you want help?

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format. To be honest, does it really matter what the file content looks like? It is far more important that the data can successfully save and load.

Comment: I'm using Node (javascript).  The format change makes it easier because i copy paste it into another application as well as using it in node.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard function for your case but if you need this **particular case** to be formatted in line-by-line mode, you can simple use string replacements like

```
fs.writeFileSync('a.json', JSON.stringify(d).replace(',{', ',\n{'),'utf8');
```

If you are on Windows, use `\r\n` instead of `\n`
Ofc this wont work on general case but the approach is clear.